# Cannot commit in mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg, hgrc

I have a Mercuirial (3.6.1) project. Every time I try to commit I get the next error.

```
(project)➜  project hg:(default) ✗ hg commit -m "TICK-190" subfolder/models.py


** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) [GCC 4.8.2]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.6.1)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/project/bin/hg", line 43, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 54, in run
    sys.exit((dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])) or 0) & 255)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 116, in dispatch
    ret = _runcatch(req)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 187, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 920, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 679, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/home/django/plantbid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1051, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1011, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 917, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 801, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 1584, in commit
    node = cmdutil.commit(ui, repo, commitfunc, pats, opts)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/cmdutil.py", line 2491, in commit
    return commitfunc(ui, repo, message, matcher, opts)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/project.py", line 1578, in commitfunc
    extra=extra)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 64, in wrapper
    return orig(repo.unfiltered(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1550, in commit
    allowemptycommit = (wctx.branch() != wctx.p1().branch()
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 533, in branch
    return encoding.tolocal(self._changeset[5].get("branch"))
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 534, in __get__
    result = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 502, in _changeset
    return self._repo.changelog.read(self.rev())
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/changelog.py", line 338, in read
    text = self.revision(node)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/revlog.py", line 1110, in revision
    bins = self._chunks(chain, df=_df)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/revlog.py", line 1015, in _chunks
    self._chunkraw(revs[0], revs[-1], df=df)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/revlog.py", line 990, in _chunkraw
    return self._getchunk(start, length, df=df)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/revlog.py", line 981, in _getchunk
    return self._loadchunk(offset, length, df=df)
  File "/home/django/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/revlog.py", line 966, in _loadchunk
    return util.buffer(d, offset - realoffset, length)
ValueError: size must be zero or positive
```

There's no much more detail I can explain. I was commiting my code without problems and suddenly this error started to show. I cannot commit any file. I can ask gor hg status with no problem.

Since this is a legacy project I've recently got, I want to make as little changes as possible.

UPDATE:

```
hg verify

repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
 changelog@?: data length off by 1066185 bytes
 changelog@?: rev 6801 points to nonexistent changeset -1
 (expected 6801)
 6802: unpacking changeset b087b38d690d: revlog decompress error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
checking manifests
 manifest@?: data length off by 1894563 bytes
 manifest@?: rev 6729 points to nonexistent changeset -1                        
 manifest@?: 000000000000 not in changesets                                     
 manifest@?: rev 6730 points to unexpected changeset 6802                       
 manifest@?: 9363dc75d5fb not in changesets                                     
 ?: reading manifest delta 9363dc75d5fb: revlog decompress error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests                                 
checking files
 plantbid/templates/rfp_edit_nursery_responses3.html@?: rev 8 points to unexpected changeset 6802
 (expected )                                                                    
 plantbid/templates/rfp_edit_nursery_responses3.html@?: 7e15c24e6859 not in manifests
 plantrfp/views.py@4684: broken revlog! (index data/plantrfp/views.py.i is corrupted)
warning: orphan revlog 'data/plantrfp/views.py.i'                               
2266 files, 6803 changesets, 13181 total revisions
3 warnings encountered!
12 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 4684)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have found a bug in Mercurial, but try updating to the latest Mercurial version (3.9) first before you file a bug report. https://www.mercurial-scm.org

Re:Update: That looks like your repository is faulty. Maybe your hard drive has errors? Is this the only copy of the repository, or is there another one somewhere else? You best bet is probably to try and find a non-broken copy.