# how to update mercurial version in ubuntu trusty to latest

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, versioning, apt-get, aptitude

I have mercurial 3.6.1, version which is not working in my project due to a bug

[Cannot commit in mercurial repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526293/cannot-commit-in-mercurial-repo/38540525#38540525)

https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5311

```
hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.6.1)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2015 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Enabled extensions:
```

Now I want to update to for example 3.8.2, but doing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
apt-get update
apt-get install mercurial
```

Does not update, and

```
sudo easy_install -U mercurial
Searching for mercurial
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mercurial/
Best match: mercurial 3.9-rc
Processing mercurial-3.9_rc-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
mercurial 3.9-rc is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing hg script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial-3.9_rc-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for mercurial
Finished processing dependencies for mercurial
```

Is the same, still the same version

```
apt-cache policy mercurial
mercurial:
  Installed: 3.8.4~trusty1
  Candidate: 3.8.4~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.4~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mercurial-ppa/releases/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.8.2-1ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.8.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy mercurial` say?

Comment: Seeing your `hg verify` output, I'm not sure updating will help you. Make sure your hard drive is alright.

Comment: @edwinksl updated with output

Comment: @DanMan what alternatives do I have?

Comment: @user1532587 See your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38540525/428241

Comment: @user1532587 As you can see from the output of `apt-cache policy mercurial`, you do have mercurial 3.8.4 installed. This means your problem is caused  by `hg` not calling mercurial 3.8.4. Can you do `readlink -e $(which hg)`?

Comment: @edwinksl readlink -e $(which hg) 
/home/django/myproj/bin/hg

Comment: @user1532587 Well there you go, for some reason, there is a `hg` in `/home/django/myproj/bin` and it is called ahead of the `hg` you had installed using `apt-get`.. Are you sure you intended for that to happen?

Comment: @edwinksl I realized I can call it via /usr/bin, anyway it does not fix the issue

Comment: At this point, your question title is no longer accurate. The `hg` that resides in `/usr/bin` is 3.8.4, which is the latest version offered by the PPA. You have mercurial installed in at least 3 different locations: 1. `/usr/bin`, 2. `/usr/local/bin` and 3. `/home/django/myproj/bin`. Are you sure this is what you wanted? Otherwise, which one of these 3 `hg`'s do you actually want? In any case, your question has deviated away from the scope of Stack Overflow and is better suited for Ask Ubuntu.